# Is it safe to use Dropbox in a shared computer?

Tags: dropbox, file-sharing

I'm using a Windows 7 PC with 2 accounts, we are sharing the computer with another colleague, so is it safe if I sync my Dropbox on this PC? The other user cannot access my files without knowing my user password, right?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Unless the files are encrypted somehow, physical access to a computer means access to everything as long as you know what you're doing.

Comment: Unless you place the Dropbox folder within your user profile, then that folder, couldn't be access by anyone with access to the computer.  If they really wanted to they could simply take control of the user profile and also access your file.  If you configure Dropbox to remember your name they could then also access your files and your Dropbox account.

Comment: @Moses since the user accounts are password protected, doesn't it mean that the files are encrypted too? Of course if they have my user password, then they can access everything. But assuming my password is secret, then can I assume my files are secret too?

Comment: @halilpazarlama see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Password-protected user profiles on Windows are not encrypted, they are password-protected. Remove/change the password (simple to do if you have the tools and know-how), and all the files in a person's profile are now accessible. Your coworker could simply remove or change your password if they knew how, and access all files in your profile.

If you want your files to be completely inaccessible by your coworker, you would need to encrypt them or the folders they are in, using a password or a keyfile that only you know. Then upload those encrypted files or containers to Dropbox. They would then sync to the computer and you could unlock them using your preferred decryption method. There are several options for this and a Google search should give you some good ones.

Another option would simply be to not sync your Dropbox files to the computer and only use a web browser to access them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. At this point, encryption won't do me much good because I constantly update the files from other computers. So I will stick with the second solution, which is accessing them from the browser.